# Gridview Column Add tooltip to column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working on an ASP.NET project and I'm trying to add a `ToolTip` on `GridView` columns header that are added from a `DataSet`. Any help please? This is the code that I'm using to bind the columns.

```
for (int i = 0; i < answers; i++)
{
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(dans.Tables[0].Rows[i]["level"].ToString(), Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for the give a tooltip to a particular column

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Utility.RowColorChange(e);
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < e.Row.Cells.Count; colIndex++)
            {
                string ToolTipString = "Edit Records";
                e.Row.Cells[5].Attributes.Add("title", ToolTipString);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK!,i your issue fixed for 2-option fixing:

1)By Design -> Set Gridview->Add Columns->Edit Column Property ->
[image]

2)By source [click here this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.tooltiptext.aspx) ,from MSDN.

Comment: column header are added from the dataset as well.

Comment: Set Gridview data source , use jQuery i fixed it: ` <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>").find("tbody tr th a").each(function (index) {
                $(this).attr("title", $(this).html());
            });
        });
    </script>` , and added your project jQuery Tooltip plugin, this code paste : `$("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>").find("tbody tr th a").tooltip();`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using JavaScript also, add a **CSS class** to the column where you want to put the tooltip. Then in JavaScript add the **title** attribute.
Following is the example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DIAGNOSIS_CODE" HeaderText="Diagnosis Code"/>
    <asp:ButtonField DataTextField="DIAGNOSIS_NAME" HeaderText="Diagnosis Name"
         ControlStyle-CssClass="DiagButton" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ICD_CODE" HeaderText="ICD Code"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ICD_NAME" HeaderText="ICD Name" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".DiagButton").attr("title", "Click to Edit Diagnosis Name");
    });
```

This will add the title Attribute to the column which has the class **.DiagButton**